# iMacros is good but unreliable. Is there any alternative?

Tags: testing, macros

iMacros is a very nice tool which allows to authomatically fill HTML forms and extract content, includes cycles and many other features. The problem is that it is quite tricky to make it extracting content properly. For example, I have failed to extract all London-to-Tokio flight prices for all the dates between 1/10/08 to 1/12/08 to find a cheapest one from expedia. Sometimes it just crashes. Does anyone know any good alternative?

Comment: I added a "testing" tag.  If this doesn't apply, feel free to remove.

Answer (score 4):

Bah, I installed it but never really used it: I am happy enough with [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/748).
[Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/install.html) can make it more edible...

Searching for URLs, I found also [DéjàClick](http://www.dejaclick.com/) and [Selenium IDE](http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/) but I don't really know them.
There are lot of other tools for Web automation, most of them professional (read "payware"...).

Alternatively, for just data extraction, I would use cURL or wget and a good HTML parser...

Answer (score 4):

I have heard good things about [Selenium IDE](http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/) also and my limited testing indicates it is pretty capable, and works in Firefox and IE.

For most any macro based testing tool, you will need to do some programming if you need to support multiple, repeatable test cases.

That said, in your example you mention running an Expedia macro... presumably to scrape results.  You will want to make sure that you don't hammer Expedia's servers, and/or expect to be booted once they discover you are (effectively) a bot.

Answer (score 3):

I agree imacros is quite unreliable. They crash quite easily if you using complex algorithm or running it continously. The trick is to close it and open it again after loops. It will decrease the number of crash you will find, though not completely.